# How to know that object is fully shrinkwrapped?

Tags: modifiers, drivers

Let's assume that I have a *Plane* moving towards a *Sphere*. When they are close enough, *Plane* is using **Shrinkwrap modifier** to stick to a *Sphere*. Now I want to add a *Driver* which depends on situation: is the *Plane* fully shrinkwrapped or not?

I do not want to use distance between objects as input for the *Driver*, because their movement is a kind of random.

So, how can I get such information from the *Shrinkwrap modifier*?